# Prove $|z_1|-|z_2|\leq|z_1-z_2|$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $z=a+ib,w=c+id\in\mathbb{C}. $Prove $|z|-|w|\leq|z-w|$

Solution: If $|z|-|w|\leq 0$ then we are done since $|z-w|\geq 0$. Suppose $|z|-|w|>0$. The stages are going backward:
$$
\\ |z|-|w|\leq|z-w|\Leftarrow 
\\ (|z|-|w|)^2\leq |z-w|^2\Leftarrow 
\\ (\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-\sqrt{c^2+d^2})^2\leq(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2\Leftarrow 
\\ ac+bd\leq c^2+d^2+\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)}
$$

How can I finish it?

Also, is there a way to solve it without using $a,b,c$ and $d$?

Comment: Hint: you can 100% copy the proof for the absolute value on $\mathbb R$. In fact, this holds on any normed space

Comment: Not a duplicate, but they do answer my question in the other problem answers.

Comment: I'm not sure of the rules, maybe it shouldn't count as a duplicate...but in addition to being a well known part of that proof, it also trivially follows by using $x \le |x|$. I'll leave it for other people to vote on if they agree

Answer (score 1):

From triangle inequality,
$$ \\ |z|=|z-w+w|\leq |z-w|+|w|\Rightarrow 
\\ |z|-|w|\leq |z-w| $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|z|-|w|\le||z|-|w||$ from properties of the absolute value. Now

$$\begin{align}
||z|-|w||\le|z-w|
&\iff(|z|-|w|)^2\le|z-w|^2\\
&\iff|z|^2-2|zw|+|w|^2\le(z-w)\overline{(z-w)}=|z|^2-(z\overline{w}+\overline{z}w)+|w|^2\\
&\iff{z\overline{w}+\overline{z}w\over2}\le|zw|\\
&\iff\Re(z\overline{w})\le|zw|
\end{align}$$

But $|zw|=|z\overline{w}|=\sqrt{(\Re(z\overline{w})^2+(\Im(z\overline{w})^2}\ge\Re(z\overline{w})$, so the inequalities above all hold. Thus

$$|z|-|w|\le||z|-|w||\le|z-w|$$

gives the desired result.